# Multiple pointers and Mark & Sweep

Tags: c, garbage-collection, programming-languages

I am trying to implement a small script language and was going to decide which garbage collection algorithm fits my benefits. I chose Mark & Sweep however i think i misunderstood the concept.

Let's say an arbitrary function is called and it creates following variables(Probably they don't have names but for the sake of simplicity assume they created in this function).

```
f() {
    /*f creates following variables*/     
    x = (1,2,(3,4,(5,6))); //this is tuple
    a = x;
    y = x[2];
    z = y[2];
    p = (10,y);
}
```

In the above example, everything is an object(integers, strings, tuples, doubles etc.) and tuples hold pointers to its objects. Moreover, every object lives in the heap. When function goes out of scope it has to delete allocated variables. Function scope looks like following.

```
+-----+
|     |
|  x  +---------->(1,2,+)
+-----+           ^    |
                  |    v
+-----+           |    (3,4,+)
|     |           |    ^    |
|  a  +-----------+    |    v
+-----+                |    (5,6)
                       |    ^
+-----+                |    |
|     |                |    |
|  y  +----------------+    |
+-----+                |    |
                       |    |
+-----+                |    |
|     |                |    |
|  z  +---------------------+
+-----+                |
                       |
+-----+                |
|     |                |
|  p  +----------->(10,+)
+-----+
```

All variables (a,x,y,z,p) have to be deleted but the question is how ? I know Mark & Sweep is a garbage collection algorithm and i thought this variables are now my garbage. Function finished its job and it has to return allocated memory to the system.

I tried following, each object holds a mark bit and after creation mark bit is set to 0. When the program pushes an object that is hold by a variable it converts its mark to 1 and no free error occurs because everyone in the program knows it has an owner. So far so good this approach has worked. But if i have a lots of variables like in the example, how can i delete multiple pointers ?

Here my assumption was, first break the ownership between x and its object. Then say every variable to mark their objects (and if the object is a tuple then it sets its objects mark bit to 1, recursively). Now (1,2,...) object's mark bit is set 1 by variable 'a'; I can try to free it but program does not allow. If i make this for every variable in my table, complexity looks like huge (i have mark and sweep phase for every object).

My question is am i correct about the Mark & Sweep algorithm ? Are the roots my variables ? How can i delete multiple pointers and even cyclic references ?

Comment: Mark & Sweep consists of two phases, as It's name stands. You need to implement Mark stage - starting from the roots (your variables) traverse all objects (your tuple and subtuples) reachable from them. Mark somehow (single bit is enough) those visited. Those not marked are garbage to be deleted - by sweeping in this case.

Comment: Then i am correct about the roots. However, do i need to sweep again and again ? For example, variable 0 (in the example its name is 'x') i broke the ownership and i sweep, after that for variable 1 same process again. Until breaking the ownership for all variables i am going to sweep so much.  I couldn't see that point because it looks like i am stopping so much to collect my garbage. @KonradKokosa

Comment: @fbgencer You mark and sweep whenever the garbage collector runs. When that is is more or less up to you. Often the GC would be invoked by the memory allocated whenever the memory consumption passes a certain threshold. Many systems also allow the programmer to invoke the GC manually (though that functionality is not used very often).

Answer (score 1):

For Mark and Sweep, you need to be able to scan all allocated objects on one side and all reachable objects on the other.

- Assuming the mark bit is clear on all allocated objects, scan all objects reachable from the root variables. When an object is found, if it is marked already, skip it, otherwise mark it and recursively enumerate the objects it points to. This phase is tricky because this recursion might go too deep, so more clever approaches are needed than plain recursion.
- Once all reachable objects have been marked, scan all allocated objects: for each object, if it is marked, clear the mark, otherwise it is unreachable, so collect it (ie: make it available for reallocation or free it).

At the end of the Sweep phase, all allocated objects are unmarked, so the assumption holds. A slightly more efficient implementation would alternate between 2 states, avoiding the need to clear the mark bit on reachable objects, thus reducing the memory bandwidth required in the sweep phase.

When you change object references during the normal course of your programs, you do not need to do anything special: just store the address of the new reference.

To effectively *delete* objects referred to from your global variables, you should just make these variables point to `null` or some other object.

The advantages of Mark & Sweep is the relative simplicity of the algorithm and the ability to collect complex structures with cycles. The disadvantage is the time taken in *stop the world* mode, especially in multi-threaded applications and real-time applications or even user interactive ones. More advanced methods have been found to deal with these issues, but their implementation can be very tricky.

Comment: Could you describe those **advanced methods** ?  Or name would be sufficient.

Comment: @fbgencer: Besides reference counting, which is a common alternative to tracing algorithms, the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science) mentions different names for advanced algorithms used in JVM implementations: G1, Parallel, ConcMarkSweep (CMS), Serial, Shenandoah... There are also Generational Garbage Collection methods used to improve cache efficiency by grouping objects according to their age. An interesting article explains the rationale and implementation of the Go lang GC: https://blog.golang.org/ismmkeynote .

Comment: @fbgencer: reference counting can be used to in real-time systems as it runs in constant time with reasonable time and space overheads. The main drawback is the inability to detect unreachable self-referencing structures. Depending on the specific memory use by the application, this might not be a problem and new techniques exist to detect such unreachable objects and collect them in a specific mark and sweep phase.